# Property not mapped by JPA to column in DB

Tags: jpa-2.0, hsqldb

I have property in my JPA model which is not mapped to any column in the database.

Because of this, the compiler says "column abc cannot be resolved".

Is there any annotation to say that the property is no longer mapped to any DB column, its just kind of utility property in JPA model.

Regards,

Satya

Answer (score 24, accepted):

add `@javax.persistence.Transient` to the property